# Solving this convex optimization problem in Python, using only SciPy

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, mathematical-optimization, convex-optimization

### Background

I'm attempting to solve the following convex optimization problem in [python](/questions/tagged/python), using (ideally) *only* the [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy) package. The goal is to recover the matrix . The matrices **ₘ**, **ₖ**, , and the integers **ℳ**,,, and  are known and fixed.

[image]

I'm given some [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) code that accomplishes this task, [using `CVXR`](http://web.cvxr.com/):

```matlab
J_M = eye(M) - 1/M*ones(M);
J_K = eye(K) - 1/K*ones(K);

S_row = [eye(M) zeros(M, K)];
S_col = [zeros(M, K); eye(K)];

cvx_begin sdp quiet
    cvx_precision low
    cvx_solver sedumi

    variable G(N, N) symmetric;
    variable B(M, K);

    DofG = diag(G)*ones(N, 1)' - 2*G + ones(N, 1)*diag(G)';
    LofG = S_row*DofG*S_col;

    G >= 0;
    G*ones(N, 1) == 0;

    L = cell(M, K);
    for m = 1:M
        for k = 1:K
            L{m, k} = [LofG(m, k) B(m, k); B(m, k) 1];
            L{m, k} >= 0;
        end
    end

    B(:) >= 0;

    minimize square_pos(norm(J_M*(B - T)*J_K, 'fro'))
cvx_end
```

Unfortunately, my knowledge of complex optimization techniques is limited (although the problem itself is, in principle, fairly straightforward), and I have no [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) experience. Some pieces of the translation are straightforward, while others I struggle with.

---

### Attempt

I've written an (admittedly very sparse) skeleton of an attempt to recreate some pieces of the [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) code.

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

def loss(...):
    # M and K are given by size of T
    J_M = eye(M) - 1/M * ones(M)
    J_K = eye(K) - 1/K * ones(K)

    DofG = diag(G) @ ones(N, 1) - 2 * G + ones(N, 1) @ diag(G)
    LofG = S_row @ DofG @ S_col

    return np.linalg.norm(J_M @ (B - T) @ J_K, 'fro')**2

res = minimize(loss, ...)
```

---

### What's Missing

I'm not sure what `G(N, N); symmetric` and `B(M, K)` do, nor how be replicated in the [python](/questions/tagged/python) code. I can't seem to find a simple explanation in the `CVXR` documentation.

I'm also unsure how to replicate the constraints on `B` and `G`, and I'm unsure how to replicate the "iterated constraint":

```matlab
    for m = 1:M
        for k = 1:K
            L{m, k} = [LofG(m, k) B(m, k); B(m, k) 1];
            L{m, k} >= 0;
        end
    end
```

### How can this Matlab implementation be translated to Python/SciPy

Comment: Would it be OK to use other python packages from PyPI or the solution has to be strictly using scipy/numpy?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to do this with scipy? IMO, it should be straightforward to implement this with [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/index.html).

Comment: @Bob If possible I'd like to use SciPy, however I'm open to and will accept answers using other packages. Thanks!

Comment: @joni There are limitations on what and how much can be installed on the machine this will be running on. If possible, I'd like to do this with SciPy (which is already available), however I'm also open to and will accept answers using other packages (e.g. CVXPY). Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will solve it with CVXPY. Thanks.

Comment: @joni, now I see your your comment, are you writing a solution already? If so I won't spend time on this.

Comment: @Bob No, I'm not, so feel free to write an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Direct translation using cvxpy

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

def solve(T, verbose=True):
    M,K = T.shape
    N = M + K
    J_M = np.eye(M) - np.ones((M,M))/M
    J_K = np.eye(K) - np.ones((K,K))/K
    S_row = np.eye(M, M+K)
    S_col = np.roll(np.eye(M+K,K), M, axis=0)

    G = cp.Variable((N,N), symmetric=True)
    B = cp.Variable((M,K))

    # Here I am assuming that the product of diag(G)*ones(N,1) is broadcasting
    Gd = cp.reshape(cp.diag(G), (N, 1))
    DofG = Gd + Gd.T - 2*G
    # Imposes N = M + K
    LofG = S_row @ DofG @ S_col
    constraints = [G >> 0, cp.sum(G, axis=1) == 0]
    for m in range(M):
        for k in range(K):
            L = cp.bmat([[LofG[m,k], B[m,k]], [B[m,k],1]])
            constraints.append(L >> 0)
    constraints.append(B >= 0)

    obj = cp.norm(J_M @ (B - T) @ J_K, 'fro')
    prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(obj), constraints)
    prob.solve(verbose=verbose)
    return G.value, B.value, obj.value
```

If you are familiar with numpy the above code should be easy to follow. The only difference is that instead of using numpy functions I use the corresponding cvxpy functions that can manipulate variables. The objects store variables and relations between them, when `prob.solve` is called it will cast the problem to a standard form and submit to some solver.

```py
solve(np.eye(3, 2) + 1)
```

```txt
(array([[ 0.68113622, -0.22048912, -0.10273289, -0.55665717,  0.19874296],
        [-0.22048912,  0.68113622, -0.10273289,  0.19874296, -0.55665717],
        [-0.10273289, -0.10273289,  0.08445099,  0.0605074 ,  0.0605074 ],
        [-0.55665717,  0.19874296,  0.0605074 ,  0.48298721, -0.1855804 ],
        [ 0.19874296, -0.55665717,  0.0605074 , -0.1855804 ,  0.48298721]]),
 array([[ 1.17174172e+00,  1.71742424e-01],
        [ 1.71742424e-01,  1.17174172e+00],
        [ 1.50334549e-15, -1.47036515e-16]]),
 6.988985781497536e-07)
```